# How to fix undefined error in js queryselector()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have similar similar HTML code (I removed unnecessary parts. now I need to read the text or the title of div like this

```html
<div _ngcontent-yjh-c166="" title="All" class="small">
      All    
  </div>
```

[all, agriculture,...]

HTML code:

```html
<zi-checkbox-tree _ngcontent-bon-c968="" _nghost-bon-c435="" class="ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" mattooltipposition="above" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip disabled-saved-search-tooltip" class="mat-tooltip-trigger checkbox-tree-container">
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox not-parent all-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="All_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-All-checkbox" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-All-checkbox">
              <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-All-checkbox-input">
              <span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-All-checkbox-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="All" class="small">
    
      All
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox checked" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted mat-checkbox-checked" aria-checked="true" data-automation-id="Agriculture_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-first-checkbox" data-automation-data="true" id="industryClassification-first-checkbox"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-first-checkbox-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-first-checkbox-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Agriculture" class="small">
    
      Agriculture
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Agriculture">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Agriculture plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Business Services_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-bizservice" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-bizservice"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-bizservice-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-bizservice-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Business Services" class="small">
    
      Business Services
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Business Services">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Business Services plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Construction_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-construction" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-construction"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-construction-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-construction-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Construction" class="small">
    
      Construction
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Construction">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Construction plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox dd-synthetics-t1-consumer-services-cb-click" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Consumer Services_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-consumerservices" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-consumerservices"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-consumerservices-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-consumerservices-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Consumer Services" class="small">
    
      Consumer Services
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Consumer Services">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Consumer Services plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Education_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-education" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-education"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-education-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-education-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Education" class="small">
    
      Education
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Education">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Education plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Energy, Utilities &amp; Waste_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-energy" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-energy"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-energy-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-energy-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Energy, Utilities &amp; Waste" class="small">
    
      Energy, Utilities &amp; Waste
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Energy, Utilities &amp; Waste">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Energy, Utilities &amp; Waste plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-node ng-star-inserted">
        <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="node-parent">
          <zi-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree-checkbox" _nghost-bon-c166="">
            <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-bon-c166="" role="checkbox" mattooltipclass="zi-tooltip" class="mat-checkbox mat-tooltip-trigger margin-box mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-checked="false" data-automation-id="Finance_checkbox"
              automationhelper="industryClassification-finance" data-automation-data="false" id="industryClassification-finance"><label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="industryClassification-finance-input"><span class="mat-checkbox-inner-container"><input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="industryClassification-finance-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-frame"></span><span class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark"><path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path></svg><span class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></span></span></span><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div _ngcontent-bon-c166="" title="Finance" class="small">
    
      Finance
    <!----><!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</span></label></mat-checkbox>
            <!---->
            <!---->





            <!---->
          </zi-checkbox>
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-options ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->

            <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" tabindex="0" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" id="" aria-label="Finance">
              <i _ngcontent-bon-c435="" data-automation-id="Finance plus_sign_icon" class="plus_sign_icon">
            </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bon-c435="" class="checkbox-tree ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
    </div>
    <!---->
  </div>
  <!---->
</zi-checkbox-tree>
```

the problem is `document.querySelectorAll('span.mat-checkbox-label > div.small')` returns the correct number, but when I want to put in a const:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.mat-checkbox-label > div.small');
```

or

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.small');
console.log(elements.length);
```

or

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.mat-checkbox-label > div.small');

elements.forEach((element) => {
  console.log(element.innerText);
});
```

or

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.mat-checkbox-label > div.small').forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.innerText);
});
```

return `undefined`

How can I get these texts or titles from these dives?

Comment: looks like angular project. Where do you try to get `const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.mat-checkbox-label > div.small');` ?

Comment: I don't see the opening of the span element, it seems that the html code is not well formatted.

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov I might not understand your question correctly, but I am trying to use javascript in the Chrome console. I just run it without applying in code before it. Do I need to navigate from the upper dives to find the one I am interested in?

Comment: @borchvm if you mean the number of <div> is not equal with </div> it is due to my mistake coping the cod, the original HTML page is working correctly, there 24 <div> tags like this so I deleted some part of the code

Comment: There is no `<span class="mat-checkbox-label">...</span>` in your example. Could this be why you don't get the result you expect?

Comment: @phuzi I updated the code with the full elements, can you check, please? Also, the original page is working but I can not find the query I want

Comment: @borchvm I updated the code with the full elements, can you check, please? Also, the original page is working but I can not find the query I want